# How to filter only duplicate comments

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, comments

Hi :) there are two columns: sentiment and comment. How to filter only duplicate comments in the dataset? Thank you four your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the columns using which you would like to output only duplicate records.

Example 1 - based on all columns in a data frame called df

```
duplicates = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)] #False means retaining all duplicates
```

Example 2 - based on a certain column or columns

```
duplicate = dictionary_df[dictionary_df[0].duplicated(keep=False)]#This is on the first column
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
df[df.comment.duplicated(False)]
```